# Why won't these shape keys export?

Tags: shape-keys

This might be plugin-specific (really hoping that's not the case), but I'm at my wits' end here.

I have a set of shape keys made entirely in Blender that I want to export out of Blender ("close jacket", "tall boots", "high back", and "straight leg"), but only some actually show up in my destination program (MikuMikuDance--relevant plugin [here](https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools)). "Tall boots" and "high back" show up perfectly, but "close jacket" doesn't show up correctly (only one/the "zipper" object is affected) and "straight leg" doesn't show up at all. Is there anything wrong with my setup that could prevent them from exporting, or what in general can prevent that from happening? I have a blend file here. Thanks!

[image]

Things I've tried:

- made sure every shape key is relative to Basis
- removed vertex group targeting (Blend from Shape -> uncheck "Add")

Comment: The issue is that you have live, generative modifiers.  No format but .blend supports mods, so the export attempts to apply these modifiers.  But given the different shapekeys, the mirror modifier leads to different topology because of the "merge" characteristic.  So several of your shapes cannot be made as shapekeys of the base shape.  Create your mirror manually instead of with a modifier and you can do this (or, use a weld modifier with a vertex group instead of "merge", that should work.)

Comment: Just to make sure I get it so I can avoid it next time: Having any modifiers at all (e.g. shrinkwrap, armature) under the wrench tab can break exports, right? Or is it just modifiers that change/increase polys like mirror or subdivide? Neither Weld nor Edit -> Symmetrize seemed to fix the issue (the latter actually broke shapekeys even in Blender), but I duplicated and multiplied by -x the pants, then merged the two objects and managed to get back its shapekey!

Comment: Looking at it again, the objects that didn't export shapekeys did all have Mirror modifiers. How can I find out what other mods are considered "live"? And incidentally, would you happen to know what causes this issue (question #214357)? It's also a shapekey problem, but it's a multi-keyed face mesh this time and I'd rather not wipe keys + apply Mirror separately for each shape key...

Comment: Still, I was able to safely export the "tall legs" shape key from the pants mesh every time. Was it because that key didn't affect vertices in the merge zone (e.g. middle groin)?

Comment: Generative modifiers (all in same column as mirror) can break it.  Some sim (ocean) can too.  All modifiers are "live" until applied or the model is exported.  If you want a general rule to follow to make sure stuff works, apply all modifiers before creating any shapekeys.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I usually import head meshes that already have shape keys attached--would I be better served manually (or X-mirror) moving vertices on both sides of an un-halved/Mirror-modded mesh, or duplicating each shape key exhaustively if I'm going to use the halve/Mirror method?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand the question.  Everything always depends, but there's nothing wrong with x-mirror editing shapekeys.  SE isn't great for extended Q&A, consider asking someplace like blenderartists.org .

Comment: I'll try one more time before asking separately. I import head meshes which already have shape keys. How best to preserve their shape even if I edit the basis shape (e.g. change a child's face into a grown-up's) or halve the mesh + add mirror modifier?

Comment: The comment sized answer is, X-mirror.  But that's not a good workflow anyways; if you edit basis, it won't take long before shapekeys no longer look appropriate.  The next, better answer is, start making your own shapekeys.